# (parameter) error: ValidationError Type 'undefined' cannot be used as an index type

Tags: typescript, yup

I am trying to perform data validation using `ValidationError` from `yup` library so that I can show a custom validation error. But when I go through the inner error, it says the path type is `undefined`.
What can I do to get it right?

```
import { ValidationError } from 'yup';

interface Errors {
    [key: string]: string;
}

export default function getValidationErrors(err: ValidationError): Errors {
    const validationErrors: Errors = {};

    err.inner.forEach(error => {
        validationErrors[error.path] = error.message;

    });
    return validationErrors;
}
```

Comment: haven't used "Yup" library but I would suggest console logging items like "err" inside the function and "error" inside the forEach to check if they are not undefined.
If they are undefined, you can place an if condition or something to tackle that.